# Why my piglatin translator code is giving unexpected output?

Tags: python-3.x

I have built a fun project named piglatin translator. It works on two principles.
1. If words in the sentence start with vowel then add "yay" at the last of the word.
2. If the word starts with consonant. Find vowel in the word transfer the constant cluster at the end and add "ay"

```
# Ask for the sentence
original=input("Enter the string.:").strip().lower()
# split the sentence
words=original.split()

# Loop through words and convert to pig latin
new_words=[]
for word in words:
  if word[0] in "aeiou":
    new_word=word+"yay"
    new_words.append(new_word)        
  else:
    vowel_pos=0
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in "aeiou":
            vowel_pos=vowel_pos+1
        else:
            break
        cons=word[:vowel_pos]
        the_rest=word[vowel_pos:]
        new_word=the_rest+cons+"ay"
        new_words.append(new_word)

#If start with vowel then add yay

# Transfer the constant cluster at the end and add ay

# Join the words
output=" ".join(new_words)
# Output the final string
print(output)
```

I have build the code. now whenever I am giving the as 
"my name is shihab"
the output shows
"ymay myay amenay isyay hihabsay ihabshay"

The output I expect is:
 "myay amenay isyay ihabshay"

Comment: Try to print `cons`, `rest_word` and `new_word`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unindent the lines starting with `cons=word[:vowel_pos]` as those are getting run for each letter as its trying to find the first vowel and you only want to run those once after you find the vowel position or reach the end of the word.

```
# Ask for the sentence
original=input("Enter the string.:").strip().lower()
# split the sentence
words=original.split()

# Loop through words and convert to pig latin
new_words=[]
for word in words:
  if word[0] in "aeiou":
    new_word=word+"yay"
    new_words.append(new_word)        
  else:
    vowel_pos=0
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in "aeiou":
            vowel_pos=vowel_pos+1
        else:
            break
    cons=word[:vowel_pos]
    the_rest=word[vowel_pos:]
    new_word=the_rest+cons+"ay"
    new_words.append(new_word)

#If start with vowel then add yay

# Transfer the constant cluster at the end and add ay

# Join the words
output=" ".join(new_words)
# Output the final string
print(output)
```

Comment: It perfectly works now. Thank you very much for your time.